# Waiting between sparql queries to D2R using Jena/ARQ - Heap Space

Tags: heap-memory, sparql, jena

I've developed an application which sends a lot of SPARQL queries to an D2R endpoint in series. I'm using jena 2.6.4 and arq 2.8.7 to query. But during execution, application stops querying D2R and waiting for a while without any reason. I searched and analyzed it using VisualVM tool, and I realized that if I trigger "Perform GC" manually, application starts querying and after a while it stops again.

I suppose that it is related with garbage collection time of my application. It seems like application has enough memory so there is no need for garbage collection, but actually for querying it must trigger garbage collection.

I want to ask that if jena has any constraint about querying and allocated resources? Is there anyone have any idea?

**NOTE :** I've allocated heap space as min:256m max:512m to application in eclipse. An also I gave 512m heap to D2R. (My computer has 4gb ram.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the root of the problem. When I've querying using ARQ in Jena, it sends a HTTP request over Jetty. In other words when you use ARQ to query, it means that you send a query to D2R over network. Therefore I suppose that D2R blocks you if you send a series of queries and you are obliged to clear something from heap.

D2R supplies an API to be able to query in series, using class "ModelD2RQ" (see : http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/bizer/d2rq/spec/#usingmodel) you can execute a lot of query consecutively at once.